# Symfony and React project without encore webpack and as "Microservices "

Tags: reactjs, symfony

so i 'am trying to create 2 microservices , one for backend and one for frontend using react and symfony , i'am using api platform in symfony , so the problem that i'am facing is i dont want to use encore , i want to seperate my projects , i just want to consume the api in front end React , is it possible ?

thank you for answering

Answer (score 1):

You can create two entirely separated applications.

One built on Symfony for the API (good idea would be to create the project via command `symfony new my_project_directory --version="6.1.*"` without the `--webapp` switch so you don't get packages you don't need).

Second application could live in a separated repository, be built on React and consume the API from first application. Completely without Symfony.

No need for webpack encore in this setup.